# Firebase FCM notification to received on IOS cordova using the Phonegap Plugin

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, push

I am trying to send a notification to IOS using FCM it does not seem to work.

My Firebase configuration seems correct:

[image]

[image]

I have added the APPLE Key to the FCM app as well as the GoogleService-Info.plist.

It looks like the app is correctly registered:

[image]

Now when I try to send a messaging using the firebase console it says done but nothing appears on the mobile.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable "Push Notifications" in the Capabilities in Xcode to receive push notifications.

[It will look like something like this in xCODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8MAS.png)

I hope this helps!!